# Background wifi scanning in Android

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-wifi

I'd started for about a month or two and I've to develop an Indoor Positioning System based on Wifi fingerprinting. I need an app that periodically scans wifi APs and send the result data to a Server.

So far I created an app that it's able to scan wifi APs and get the results when different connections are detected. I'm doing this in main activity using a broadcast receiver. The app is also able to send the data to the server.

What I want now is move this process to a periodic process in background, even when the smartphone is in sleep mode.

I have already read some topics about how to do it but none was clear. My question is what is the best way to do this? Using a Service/IntentService with a Timer/TimerTask?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Thanks!! AlarmManager and Services work fine!

Comment: The current answers don't tell you that you will also need a wake lock for your code to run while phone is asleep.

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer. Also "_WAKEUP" versions of alarms are worth mentioning..

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement it..

Comment: have you implemented, can you please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) fits your needs, use [`setRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to set something to repeat every X time

> Schedule a repeating alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks,
>   timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If
>   there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will
>   first be canceled.
>
> Like set(int, long, PendingIntent), except you can also supply a
>   period at which the alarm will automatically repeat. This alarm
>   continues repeating until explicitly removed with
>   cancel(PendingIntent). If the stated trigger time is in the past, the
>   alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on
>   how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat
>   interval.
>
> If an alarm is delayed (by system sleep, for example, for non _WAKEUP
>   alarm types), a skipped repeat will be delivered as soon as possible.
>   After that, future alarms will be delivered according to the original
>   schedule; they do not drift over time. For example, if you have set a
>   recurring alarm for the top of every hour but the phone was asleep
>   from 7:45 until 8:45, an alarm will be sent as soon as the phone
>   awakens, then the next alarm will be sent at 9:00.
>
> If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in
>   order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always
>   elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time
>   alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm
>   delivery.
>
> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

> Parameters
>
> **type** One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC,
>   or RTC_WAKEUP.
>
> **triggerAtMillis**   time in milliseconds that the alarm
>   should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the
>   alarm type).
>
> **intervalMillis**    interval in milliseconds between
>   subsequent repeats of the alarm.
>
> **operation** Action to perform when the
>   alarm goes off; typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

As the note says

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

But i don't think you care much if it's not precise.

---

Or you can use [`setInexactRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements;
>   for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at
>   the top of every hour. These alarms are more power-efficient than the
>   strict recurrences traditionally supplied by setRepeating(int, long,
>   long, PendingIntent), since the system can adjust alarms' delivery
>   times to cause them to fire simultaneously, avoiding waking the device
>   from sleep more than necessary.
>
> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time. In
>   addition, while the overall period of the repeating alarm will be as
>   requested, the time between any two successive firings of the alarm
>   may vary. If your application demands very low jitter, use one-shot
>   alarms with an appropriate window instead; see setWindow(int, long,
>   long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).
>
> As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. Because this method
>   has been available since API 3, your application can safely call it
>   and be assured that it will get similar behavior on both current and
>   older versions of Android.

> Parameters
>
> **type**  One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC,
>   or RTC_WAKEUP.
>
> **triggerAtMillis**   time in milliseconds that the alarm
>   should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the
>   alarm type). This is inexact: the alarm will not fire before this
>   time, but there may be a delay of almost an entire alarm interval
>   before the first invocation of the alarm.
>
> **intervalMillis**    interval in
>   milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm.
>
> Prior to API 19,
>   if this is one of INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
>   INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, or INTERVAL_DAY then the alarm will
>   be phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups.
>   Otherwise, the alarm will be set as though the application had called
>   setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent). As of API 19, all
>   repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other
>   alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval. operation  Action to
>   perform when the alarm goes off; typically comes from
>   IntentSender.getBroadcast().

While my answer aim is to say a general way to repeat an action every X time, as other noticed, you will need [Wifi Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html), [Wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) and use [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) as AlarmManager type.

> **RTC_WAKEUP**: 
>   Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC),
>   which will wake up the device when it goes off.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from Activity to Service. Then, start the service periodically using AlarmManager. Service does the scanning and stops self when it is done. Then it is started again when timer elapses.

EDIT: Also look at [cpu lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and [wifi lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html).

EDIT2: Also when creating alarm, use [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) constant so that your action is triggered even if the device is in sleep mode.